# Create Parse user without internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I'm using the following code for the creation of a user,

```
[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
```

but since I have no interest connection I get an error that there is no internet connection, and `[PFUser currentUser]` stays nil.

I thought that with the local data store Parse would create the user but I am obviously wrong, is there a way to create a user without internet connection?

Comment: Why allow the user to continue using your application if it's dependent on signing up? simply don't allow them to move forward until they can successfully sign up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and it's really easy. You can enable automatic users when you initialize Parse. That way, `[PFUser currentUser]` will not be nil.

```
[PFUser enableAutomaticUser];
```

The user object will not even attempt to save to Parse until that user performs a save method.

Later, you can detect if you have a logged in user or an anonymous user by calling:

```
[PFAnonymousUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a lot of people have been saying that this is not possible there could be a simple work around. You could have some code checking if the user is connected to a data plan and if they aren't instead of using the code of saving it to Parse you would save the account details to variables and once the user is connected to Parse it could upload those variables to the _User class in Parse.

I hope this helps. ~Arman

Answer (score -1):

In order for `[PFUser currentUser]` to work, Parse needs to open a session,  so it will need a valid internet connection or an active 2g, 3g, or 4g data plan.

To create the functionality of `[PFUser currentUser]` I would recommend using CoreData.

You can create an Entity "User" and add all the values you add in parse into the CoreData store. While you wait for Parse to save the current user and open a session you can use the User in your data base.

You can also create a category for the "User" entity and add all the functionalities like `currentUser`

If you choose to go that way here is a good CoreData [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-core-data-and-batch-updates--cms-22164) you can also look at the Stanford University coreData class [video](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stanford%20ios%20core%20data)

Comment: Creates more work than necessary, in my opinion. If you were going to do it this why not just don't it with built in functionality local datastore? You don't need to reconstruct your entire app to include Core Data when even a plist would suffice, or NSUserDefaults but pinning objects is essentially the same thing as Core Data

Comment: It may be a bit more work then using NSUserDefaults, but it is way more understandable and could be documented. Creating this func in CoreData if not that hard to do and it creates order in your code.

Comment: Way more understandable and could be documented, as plists and NSUserDefaults aren't? It was just my opinion. I just don't like it myself when people down vote and disregard leaving a comment on why. So I'm supporting the cause, the OP ultimately will decide what works for them.